# How to decode the following Ascii (?) string to text?

Tags: html, ascii, arabic

I have the following Arabic character string used in HTML :

```
&#1576;&#1575;&#1604; &#1608;&#1602;&#1585;&#1609; &#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1593;&#1605;&#1604;&#1578; &#1573;&#1584;, &#1605;&#1593; &#1580;&#1593;&#1604
```

I try to decode it to text. What is it exactly?
Thanks!
full html code:

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto;" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                     <tr>
                                                                        <td dir="rtl" style="font-family:'Roboto', Arial, Sans-serif; font-weight:400; color:#E6A244; font-size:16px; line-height:24px;" align="right">
                                                                           &#1576;&#1575;&#1604; &#1608;&#1602;&#1585;&#1609; &#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1593;&#1605;&#1604;&#1578; &#1573;&#1584;, &#1605;&#1593; &#1580;&#1593;&#1604; &#1575;&#1604;&#1582;&#1591;&#1617;&#1577; &#1604;&#1578;&#1602;&#1604;&#1610;&#1593;&#1577;, &#1601;&#1589;&#1604; &#1601;&#1610; &#1608;&#1608;&#1589;&#1601; &#1602;&#1616;&#1576;&#1604;. &#1607;&#1584;&#1575; &#1593;&#1604; &#1610;&#1585;&#1578;&#1576;&#1591; &#1578;&#1603;&#1578;&#1610;&#1603;&#1575;&#1611; &#1604;&#1610;&#1578;&#1587;&#1606;&#1617;&#1609;. &#1602;&#1576;&#1604; &#1605;&#1593; &#1573;&#1593;&#1575;&#1583;&#1577; &#1573;&#1581;&#1603;&#1575;&#1605;, &#1610;&#1576;&#1602; &#1571;&#1585;&#1575;&#1590;&#1610; &#1578;&#1586;&#1575;&#1605;&#1606;&#1575;&#1611; &#1602;&#1583;. &#1635;&#1632; &#1576;&#1607;&#1575; &#1608;&#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1605;&#1585; &#1575;&#1602;&#1578;&#1589;&#1575;&#1583;&#1610;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1571;&#1608;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;&#1610;&#1606;, &#1576;&#1610;&#1606; &#1605;&#1606; &#1634;&#1632;&#1632;&#1636; &#1576;&#1575;&#1604;&#1580;&#1575;&#1606;&#1576;. &#1576;&#1610;&#1606; &#1578;&#1605; &#1608;&#1575;&#1606;&#1607;&#1575;&#1569; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1589;&#1576;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1587;&#1575;&#1581;&#1604;, &#1602;&#1575;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1571;&#1585;&#1590;&#1610;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1578;&#1603;&#1575;&#1604;&#1610;&#1601; &#1578;&#1605;, &#1580;&#1615;&#1604; &#1603;&#1604; &#1576;&#1588;&#1585;&#1610;&#1577; &#1604;&#1610;&#1585;&#1578;&#1601;&#1593; &#1604;&#1605;&#1581;&#1575;&#1603;&#1605;. &#1590;&#1585;&#1576; &#1575;&#1578;&#1617;&#1580;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1571;&#1608;&#1604;&#1609; &#1575;&#1604;&#1573;&#1605;&#1578;&#1593;&#1575;&#1590; &#1593;&#1604;, &#1571;&#1610; &#1576;&#1608;&#1575;&#1576;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1579;&#1602;&#1610;&#1604;&#1577; &#1583;&#1608;&#1606;, &#1575;&#1606; &#1571;&#1590;&#1601; &#1585;&#1574;&#1610;&#1587; &#1576;&#1587;&#1576;&#1576; &#1587;&#1610;&#1575;&#1587;&#1577;. &#1583;&#1575;&#1585; &#1632;&#1640;&#1632;&#1636; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1580;&#1578;&#1605;&#1593; &#1579;&#1605;, &#1584;&#1604;&#1603; &#1610;&#1593;&#1576;&#1571; &#1576;&#1607;&#1610;&#1574;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1588;&#1578;&#1575;&#1569;&#1548; &#1608;. 
                                                                        </td>
                                                                     </tr>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried?

Comment: I have tried online HTML entities Encoder / Decoder with no luck. Trying to find out what kind of encoding it is.

Comment: If you paste the String into the browser address bar and hit enter it will show you what it says. After doing this clearly I can tell you it is not part of the ASCII code table.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have added the html code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML uses Unicode. The entities are Unicode codepoints. In this case, the numeric entity references have the codepoints as decimal numbers.

[ب](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0628/index.htm) is the first one.